# Can we read inner xml nodes in Data Driven Test in XML datasource?

Tags: c#, xml, unit-testing

If I have this sample of code, using XML as datasource:

```
[DeploymentItem("Ita_ResultArea_CompaniesList\\snapshot.xml")]
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML",
            "|DataDirectory|\\Ita_ResultArea_CompaniesList\\snapshot.xml", 
            "Test", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
[TestMethod]
public void Ita_ResultArea_Tdd_MinimalRequest()
{
    var input = TestContext.DataRow["Input"];
    Assert.IsNotNull(input);
}
```

Why I cannot read internal nodes from **TestContext.DataRow["Input"]**?

XML content is next:

```
<TestData>

<Test>
  <Input>
    <Query>
      <Expression>laser &lt;IN&gt; FTXT</Expression>
    </Query>
  </Input>
  <Output>
    <someOut>ss</someOut>
  </Output>
</Test>

<Test>
  <Input>
    <Query>
      <Expression>laser &lt;IN&gt; FTXT</Expression>
    </Query>
  </Input>
  <Output>
    <someOut>ss</someOut>
  </Output>
</Test>

</TestData>
```

I found some threads in MSDN forum, that it was impossible to read many-level xml files, just straightforward examples, like this:

```
<TestData>
 <Test>
  <sample1>some text</sample1>
  <sample2>some test</sample2>
 </Test>
</TestData>
```

In this way **TestContext.DataRow["sample1"]** works fine.

---

**Updated**
As result I dealed with my xml file in next way (look at source xml):

```
<TestData>
  <Test>
    <Expression1>laser &lt;IN&gt; FTXT</Expression1>
    <someOut1>ss<someOut1>
    <Expression2>laser &lt;IN&gt; FTXT</Expression2>
    <someOut2>ss<someOut2>
  </Test>
  <!-- another test data-->
  <Test>
    <Expression1>lorem ipsum</Expression1>
    <someOut1>found<someOut1>
    <Expression2>oneWord</Expression2>
    <someOut2>found<someOut2>
    <Expression3>long data</Expression3>
    <someOut3>found<someOut3>
  </Test>
</TestData>
```

That is not pretty fine solution, as you can see, but hand-made workaround:
I joined inner levels of xml into first level only, retrieving only meaningful data.
So in .NET code, running test, you must manually restore full hierarchy with test data.

I was critisized at my company by colleagues, but alternative was only as **BClaydon** proposed.

Seems Microsoft doesn't bother about this restriction for years.

Comment: What did you end up doing? I just asked the same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22644016/data-driven-test-on-visual-studio-using-a-complex-serialized-object). I believe we could use CDATA to trick the XML parser that it's dealing with a big string, but it's not my preferred solution.

Comment: I updated question with my solution. Trick with CDATA maybe helpful, but I believe,  that using CDATA is "old-school" decision :).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how extensive your unit testing is, but if you're going to validate that your XML matches some 'control' data set then you'll want to use a dataset.  I am currently unit testing SSRS reports against 'known good' transactional queries, SQL tables, or datasets. XML in datasets are broken out in to logical datatables with the names of the nodes. You can now call the name of the node (a datatable), row index, column name, cell, etc.

Comment: Thanks, BClaydon, but I'd like to use XML instead of SQL tables. My unit testing is not such extensive. 
Also I don't want to add additional SQL database for unit testing.

Comment: I use C# DataSets, which are created and destroyed in memory, and don't use SQL; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8bw9ksd6.aspx  If you see your XML in a DataSet in debugger you may find a use for it. There are examples online. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx29c3yd(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok, BClaydon, I understood your position - we can load Xml into DataSets and operate with data, like in ADO.NET. But I'd like implement TDD by means of MSTest framework and investigate, why there is such an awful limitation.